# Find $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sinh x -\sin x}{\cosh x - \cos x}$

Tags: limits, hyperbolic-functions

> Find $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sinh x -\sin x}{\cosh x - \cos x}$$

I used Hopital and couldn't find the answer which is $0$.

Comment: How many times did you differentiate the numerator & denominator? One isn't enough, but two would have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Apply L'Hopital's rule TWO times:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sinh x -\sin x}{\cosh x - \cos x}\stackrel{H}{=}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cosh x -\cos x}{\sinh x + \sin x}\stackrel{H}{=}\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sinh x +\sin x}{\cosh x + \cos x}=?$$

Answer (score 3):

Using Taylor series, $\sinh x-\sin x=\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)$ while $\cosh x-\cos x=x^2+o(x^2)$, so the fraction is $\frac{x}{3}+o(x)$. This proves the limit is $0$, whether we take $x\to 0^+$ or $x\to 0^-$.